# how to look at each registry key and run install file?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get back the list of Registry key's and based on those keys certain install files for languages need to be run.

So, the key I am looking at is `hklm:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages` and I can get back all the languages installed. However, slightly lost as to how to run install files based on each key value found. I tried the below as first cause but that just returns each language on a single line - I cannot proceed as I want the code to look at the first language and then set a case against that possibly.

So - if `en-US` is installed then run a specific language installer file.
**then** (as a server could have multiple languages installed) if `es-ES` is found then run that installer and continue until all the registry keys are done.

The below is what I have thus far:

```
$langInstalled = Get-ChildItem -Path hklm:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages | Select -ExpandProperty PSChildName

$langInstalled | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "Languages Installed $langInstalled" }
```

Here is the output of the above with a server that has multiple languages installed - as there are 7 languages installed it displays it in seven lines and each line showing the exact same result - I was hoping for one key returned per line:

```
Languages Installed de-DE en-US es-ES fr-FR it-IT nl-NL pt-PT
Languages Installed de-DE en-US es-ES fr-FR it-IT nl-NL pt-PT
Languages Installed de-DE en-US es-ES fr-FR it-IT nl-NL pt-PT
Languages Installed de-DE en-US es-ES fr-FR it-IT nl-NL pt-PT
Languages Installed de-DE en-US es-ES fr-FR it-IT nl-NL pt-PT
Languages Installed de-DE en-US es-ES fr-FR it-IT nl-NL pt-PT
Languages Installed de-DE en-US es-ES fr-FR it-IT nl-NL pt-PT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$langInstalled` is an array of strings, so when you drop it into a string like that, it outputs a space separated list of those strings. Since there are 7 strings and you iterate over each with `ForEach-Object`, you see the list 7 times.

Change `$langInstalled` inside the `ForEach-Object` block to `$_`:

```
$langInstalled | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "Languages Installed $_" }
```

[`$_` is an automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) refering to the "current object in the pipeline"

You can also shortcut the `Select-Object` statement by using `Get-ChildItem -Name`:

```
$RegKeyPath = HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages
@(Get-ChildItem -Path $RegKeyPath -Name) |ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Language installed: $_"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - works really well and understood about $_